# Can view web page in browser window, but downloading it in PowerShell 2.0 returns no content

Tags: .net, web-services, powershell, windows-7, powershell-2.0

I am trying to download content from a custom PHP web service using PowerShell v2.0. The content is a short string (i.e. "[123]"), and can be accessed through Internet Explorer, but returns no content when System.Net.Webclient.DownloadString() is called, nor does it generate any errors. Here is the code that is being called:

```
$url = "https://localserver/servicename.php?param1=x&param2=y"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.Webclient
$content = $wc.DownloadString($url)
```

After this code is called, $content contains an empty string. Using other URLs, this code returns valid content. Is there another way in PowerShell 2.0 to download the content exactly as it is viewed in the browser, regardless of headers that may or may not be set by the web service?

Comment: Is your browser using a proxy?

Comment: Hi dugas, the browser isn't using a proxy

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending the same user agent string as your browser?

`$wc.Headers.Add('user-agent', '...')`

Comment: Hi mousio,
I passed my browser string, but the result was the same. The server does require login information, but adding
    $webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pwdOut)
was ineffective.  I did, however, login through the browser successfully.  Will this logged-in session carry over when accessing the page through PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved (sort of). The issue was that the page required a non-basic authentication on a separate web page. I bypassed it by editing code on the server, but could not solve the problem from within powershell